How to convert strings to the same pattern
I have some sets of random strings. These strings may have one of the special characters (+,-,=) as a prefix or suffix, or both. Different special characters cannot be mixed in the same set.
I want to convert the strings in a set into the same pattern depending on how the special characters are attached. For example, if a set of strings contains some strings with a special character as a prefix and some as a suffix, all strings in the set must have the special character at both the beginning and the end.　 Also, if all strings do not have any special character, the set does not change.
My attempt is as follows:
convert[n_, x_] := Block[{temp = x}, 
      If[Select[temp, StringMatchQ[#, n ~~ __] &] != {},temp = n <> # & /@ temp];
      If[Select[temp, StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ n] &] != {},temp = # <> n & /@ temp];
      StringReplace[#, n <> n :> n] & /@ temp]

sampledata = {{"-Qrs2","tu44-"},{"abC23+","dE45f","+gh+"}, 
 {"=ijk56","=LkM23","nop"},{"vw77","xyz"}}
          
convert["=", convert["-", convert["+", #]]] & /@ sampledata

gives results as desired:
{{"-Qrs2-","-tu44-"},{"+abC23+","+dE45f+","+gh+"},
 {"=ijk56","=LkM23","=nop"},{"vw77","xyz"}}

But I think there must be a more efficient way.

Can you clarify a bit?  In the list {"=ijk56","=LkM23","nop"} the rule seems to be that if there is a special character used only as a prefix on any member of the list, then the output list must have that special character as a prefix on all members.  And if a special character appears only as a suffix, all members of the output list would have that special character as a suffix (only).  Have I got those two cases right?

Yes, that's right.

This is a more general implementation, and it happens to be a bit faster, although I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "efficient". It might require some explanation (see below).
mergeAffixes[affixes : {__String}, strings : {__String}] :=
  With[
    {re = RegularExpression[ToString@StringForm["(^[`1`]?)([^`1`]+)([`1`]?)$", StringJoin[DeleteDuplicates@affixes]]]},
    StringJoin /@ Thread[MapAt[StringJoin@*Union, Flatten[StringCases[strings, re -> {"$1", "$2", "$3"}], {2, 3}], {{1}, {-1}}]]]

Demonstration with your sample data:
sampledata = {{"-Qrs2", "tu44-"}, {"abC23+", "dE45f", "+gh+"}, {"=ijk56", "=LkM23", "nop"}, {"vw77", "xyz"}};
mergeAffixes[{"-", "+", "="}, #] & /@ sampledata
(* {{"-Qrs2-", "-tu44-"}, {"+abC23+", "+dE45f+", "+gh+"}, {"=ijk56", "=LkM23", "=nop"}, {"vw77", "xyz"}} *)

The basic idea is to capture all the prefixes and suffixes and "roots" in one pass through the list using a regular expression. Then we can join the affix lists into a single affix each. And then we can thread everything back together.
You could skip building the regular expression based on the input affixes if you want to hard code the affixes. The regular expression we're trying to get looks like this (for your specific case of -, +, =):
RegularExpression["(^[-+=]?)([^-+=]+)([-+=]?)$"]

You can read the docs for RegularExpression if that's confusing. An expression like [-+=] means to match on any instance of the group of characters within the square brackets. The ? means one or zero characters match. So, that's the affixes. Putting the ^ inside the square brackets means to match by excluding the group, so any character that is NOT -,+,=. And the + means 1 or more characters matching. The ^ at the beginning means match the beginning of the string, and the $ at the end means match the end of the string. The round brackets create groups that we can refer to during replacement. If you jump ahead to look at StringCases, you'll see that we refer to $1, $2, and $3, which means the first, second, and third "submatch" in the match.
Everything else is restructuring and regrouping the resulting match result.
To demonstrate the generality:
mergeAffixes[{"*", "~"}, {"~abc*", "~def", "ghi~"}]
(* {"~abc*~", "~def*~", "~ghi*~"} *)

This might not actually fit your use case, but I didn't know your full context. One other generalization that I chose not to do would be to allow matches on affixes longer than a single character (which would make sense give the output of the sample I just gave), but that's an easy modification to the regular expression if desired. I also didn't try to deal with the situation of special characters appearing inside the "root". That modification might be a bit tricky, but I'm not sure.

Thank you. I hadn't thought of the regular expression so your method is very helpful.
